# How get fast multiple rows in Go?

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have troubles with performance when I get 20k-50k and more rows from `SELECT * FROM table` in `rows.scan(&a, &b...)`. I don't know how to use concurrency in this case because I need to use `rows.Next()` for iterating, and I can't do it in concurrency.

Performance drops only when I scan results from rows to structure's fields in `rows.Scan`.

The query takes 5-15 ms, but scanning takes (40k rows) 800-2000ms.

Thank you!

Comment: mysql or postgresql?

Comment: in my case is postgresql. But I think it not depends on database.

Comment: Post your table schema as well.

Comment: Are you by any chance using paging techniques in your queries? Or is it just a simple select to read all the rows? Also, the network topology could also affect your read performance. There is quite a bit of detail you're omitting here.

Comment: @AmirKeibi it is a simple query, which returning JSON. DB and server are placed on single VM.

Comment: Then I'd say the problem is either the I/O in the database or the amount of memory available to the application. When scanning through the rows, that's when the actual I/O occurs. If you have access to a SSD drive, you could try moving the data files there and measure the difference.

Comment: @AmirKeibi I don't agree. My DB store data on SSD. I think the cause of the trouble is scanning rows in Go.

Comment: The scan doesn't do anything special. It reads the rows through the cursor. How many columns (and what sizes) are you reading by the way?

Comment: @AmirKeibi Maybe... I reading 10 VARCHAR(100) columns and 3 JSON columns. I think cause of the trouble is a reading JSON, because it's unmarshalling and it's slow operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 'rows.Next()' is sequential, you would need to split your query into multiple statements, and then work concurrently on them.

```
func main() {

    queries := []string{
        "SELECT * FROM abc where a < 10000",
        "SELECT * FROM abc where a >= 10000 && a <= 30000",
        "SELECT * FROM abc where a > 30000",
    }

    for _, query := range queries {
        go dbCall(query)
    }
}

func dbCall(query string) {

    rows, _ := db.Query(query)
    for rows.Next() {
        var a, b, c int
        _ = rows.Scan(&a, &b, &c)
        // Process row
    }
}
```

Use channels, locks, etc when necessary, based on your use case.

Comment: Is cause of performance drops a scanning in Golang? It doesn't depend on DB? If I use `OFFSET` for splitting query, would it a cause of dropping?

Comment: @arzonus It varies from case to case, you need to benchmark your particular setup to get a conclusive answer on that. And regarding using `OFFSET`, if you're concerned about concurrent writes, you can execute the statements within a transaction.